# Surface view image not expand

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, textureview

I am developing the android H264 Video rendering application.While rendering the H264 video stream i am using the MediaCodec API.I get the surface object from Texture View and pass the surface reference to the MediaCodec API.It renders the video perfectly in all the devices models. While pausing the video and zooming the texture view the view can be extend whereas the image on the surface view is not extend.

Comment: Post some code, what you have tried till now??

Comment: Please refer this link sample code :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121145/pinch-zoom-effect-with-android-surfaceview